# Compass Sprites in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, compass-sass, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I get this error when trying to do spiriting with compass.

```
Template::Error (can't convert Array into String
    (in /Volumes/Terra-Nova/jwaldrip/Sites/resipsa/app/assets/stylesheets/home.css.scss)):
```

Here is my code within my scss file:

```
@import "icon/*.png";
@include all-icon-sprites;
```

My images are in "app/assets/images/icon/"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: do your `.png` files exist? [looks like someone got a similar error with files that don't exist](https://groups.google.com/group/compass-users/browse_thread/thread/8539c9c72e562921). If they do exist, I would check if chunky_png and/or oily_png are installed correctly. [They are used to generate the sprites](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took some time and some research but the issue was that I was using the gem "compass" where I should have used "compass-rails" adding this gem fixed all my issues and compass is not importing the pngs and generating the sprites.